# Programatically add a simple pause to a video

Tags: python, matplotlib, command-line, ffmpeg

Say I have a 30s video. I want to produce a 40s video that is just the first video but with an extra "freezed" frame (for say 10s) somewhere in the middle of it. (think of it as wanting to comment the video at a specific point)

I know I can do this easily with video editing software. However, I am looking for a command line tool that allows me to do this efficiently (I need to do this several times with variable points to freeze the video)

I am using Python

I thought of using ffmpeg, splitting the video into two, creating a third video composed of a given frame, and then concatenating the three videos.

But maybe there is a much simpler technique?

Comment: The approach you mentioned sounds reasonable to me. All the heavy lifting is done by ffmpeg. You can do what you like in about 50 lines of code. For the pause video, you can use ffmpeg to stack images (e.g. all in a folder) into a video stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it

Let's say I have the original movie file: in.mp4
and I want to pause it for 10 seconds with the frame found at the 15s mark

```
#first extract the frame
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:15 -i in.mp4 -vframes 1 -q:v 2 -y static_frame.png

# Create the movie_aux1.mp4 of the first part of the original video
ffmpeg -t 00:00:15 -i in.mp4 movie_aux1.mp4
# Create the movie_aux2.mp4
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i static_frame.png -t 10 movie_aux2.mp4
# Create the movie_aux3.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:15 -i in.mp4 movie_aux3.mp4

# Create a list of the movies to concatenate. Dont forget to erase this file afterwards
echo "file 'movie_aux1.mp4'" >> mylist.txt
echo "file 'movie_aux2.mp4'" >> mylist.txt
echo "file 'movie_aux3.mp4'" >> mylist.txt

# Concatenate all three movies
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt out.mp4
```